# Request data event on express with nodeJS doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, express

I'm trying to do some file upload using express but I'm having an issue on the request data event.
The data event doesn't work even if I put some console logging test on it.

Here's my server code:

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();

//parser
app.use(express.bodyParser());


//form
app.get('/', function (req, res){
    res.sendfile(__dirname + "/upload.html");
});

//post
app.post('/', function(req, res){
        var imageName = req.files.image.name;
        //error
        if(!imageName){
            console.log("Error");
            res.redirect("/");
            res.end();
        } else {

                var file = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + "/uploads/" + imageName);
                var fileSize = req.headers['content-length'];
                var uploadedSize = 0;
                req.on('data', function (chunk) {
                    var bufferStore = file.write(chunk);
                    if(bufferStore == false)
                        req.pause();
                    uploadedSize += chunk.length;
                    uploadProgress = (uploadedSize/fileSize) * 100;
                    console.log(Math.round(uploadProgress) + "%" + " uploaded\n" );
                });
                file.on('drain', function() {
                    req.resume();
                });

                req.on('end', function() {
                    console.log('Upload done!');
                    res.end();
                });
        }

});
app.listen(5000);
```

And here's my client code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <body>
        <form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        <input type='file' name='image'/>
        <input type='submit' /></form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this module:

```
var path = require('path');
```

Then, try to replace your post action with this:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    var uploadDir = __dirname + '/uploads/';

    if( !path.existsSync(uploadDir) ){
        fs.mkdirSync(uploadDir, 0755);
    }

    var filename = req.files.image.name;
    fs.readFile(req.files.image.path, function (err, data) {
        var save_path = uploadDir + filename;
        fs.writeFile(save_path, data, function (err) {
            if(err){
                res.json({
                    error: 'Error!'
                });
            } else {
                res.json({
                    success: true
                });
            }
            fs.unlink(req.files.image.path, function (err) {
              if (err) throw err;
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Worked flawlessly, but can't I use that as a stream? I'm trying to display the progress as the upload runs, is there another way to do it without streaming?

Comment: You can try this: http://new-bamboo.co.uk/blog/2012/01/10/ridiculously-simple-ajax-uploads-with-formdata